# R-pi Booting Issue

Tags: boot-issues

I'm stuck with my RPi. When I powered it up with the pre-installed NOOBS card, both LEDs (ACT & PWR) are glowing solidly. My connected screen also displays no response.

What could cause this problem?. [image: photo of board]

Comment: Can you please explain how you prepared your SD card

Comment: Yup. I downloaded the NOOBS for rpi.org and Extracted it. I formatted my SD card using SDFORMATTER and copied the files into it.

Comment: How big is your card? I had the same problems with NOOBS instillation when I first tried. I thought it was a power supply problem from everything I read. I tried different power supplies with no success. I changed to Raspbarian and everything worked. However, this is some time ago and I have no explanation for why Raspbarian worked.

Comment: When you say copied the files onto the card, you mean you used something like Win32DiskImager to copy the image to the SD card, right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just copy the image to sd card. You should write it on a disk, because it need to make partitions on your sd card. 
You can use **Win32DiskImager** on Windows or **dd** on Linux.

Guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md